# Why http PUT can upload file successfully to SharePoint?

Tags: powershell, security, http-400-bad-request, post

We are using SP2016 on-premise. In order to handle security test I prepared a PowerShell script to test upload with PUT/POST.

```
$Digest = $response.getcontextwebinformation.FormDigestValue
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$Headers.Add("accept","application/json;odata=verbose")
$Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest",$Digest)
Invoke-WebRequest -method Post -UseDefaultCredentials -uri $url -InFile $uploadPath -headers $Headers
```

By using above script I can upload my file successfully. Return status code is 200.

Then I change the `-method` to `PUT`. The file STILL upload successfully. However the status code return is

> Remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Is it normal SharePoint behavior? Why SharePoint allow file upload while returning 400 error? Is it possible we can disallow PUT on SharePoint?

Comment: (Old thread!) I don't think you have to provide a X-RequestDigest header when calling sharepoint api from outside the http web application.

Comment: @SteveB sorry I don't have a chance to test. But my point is, if SharePoint allow me upload the file, why it return 400 error?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Whether I provide digest or not, I can successfully upload a file, without any trouble. To narrow the diagnostic, can you describe how you build the url, and what is the body of the response ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps, here's a working example of file upload:

```
$siteColl = "http://mysharepoint/sites/mycoll"
$targetFolder = "MyLib"

$fileToUpload = "D:\path\to\mydocument.docx"

$creds = if(-not $creds) { Get-Credential } else { $creds }

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$sitecoll/$targetFolder/mydocument.docx"  `
                  -InFile $fileToUpload   `
                  -Credential $creds   `
                  -Method Put
```

This results in 200 return code

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
                    ResourceTag: rt:6E1D7470-0B2E-4332-BE74-C2B16B386DFA@00000000004
                    Public-Extension: http://schemas.microsoft.com/repl-2
                    SPRequestGuid: 5c530ca0-3ea5-7036-...
Headers           : {[X-SharePointHealthScore, 0], [ResourceTag, rt:6E1D7470-0B2E-4332-BE74-C2B16B386DFA@00000000004], 
                    [Public-Extension, http://schemas.microsoft.com/repl-2], [SPRequestGuid, 
                    5c530ca0-3ea5-7036-e490-00894a0829ce]...}
RawContentLength  : 0
```